# Is there a way to get a list of possible exceptions in Python 3.x?

Tags: exception, python-3.x

In Python 2.7, you can do this to see a list of exceptions:

```
import exceptions

    for i in dir(exceptions):
    print (i)
```

Is there something similar for Python 3.2? There's no module "exceptions" for one thing. I know you can iterate on Exception, but that doesn't give you a list of all the possible exceptions, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: (There is no fixed set of exceptions; new ones can be defined.)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (not pretty, but works) to get a list of the builtin exceptions:

```
>>> exes = [ex for ex in vars(__builtins__).values() 
...         if hasattr(ex, '__mro__') and issubclass(ex, BaseException)]
>>> exes
[<class 'IndexError'>, <class 'SyntaxError'>, <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, 
<class 'NameError'>, <class 'BytesWarning'>, <class 'IOError'>, <class 'SystemExit'>,
<class 'RuntimeWarning'>, <class 'Warning'>, <class 'UnicodeTranslateError'>,
<class 'EOFError'>, <class 'BufferError'>, <class 'FloatingPointError'>, 
<class 'FutureWarning'>, <class 'ImportWarning'>, <class 'ReferenceError'>, 
<class 'TypeError'>, <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>, <class 'UserWarning'>, 
<class 'ResourceWarning'>, <class 'SystemError'>, <class 'BaseException'>, 
<class 'RuntimeError'>, <class 'MemoryError'>, <class 'StopIteration'>, 
<class 'LookupError'>, <class 'UnicodeError'>, <class 'ImportError'>, 
<class 'Exception'>, <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>, <class 'SyntaxWarning'>, 
<class 'ArithmeticError'>, <class 'GeneratorExit'>, <class 'KeyError'>, 
<class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>, <class 'EnvironmentError'>, <class 'OSError'>, 
<class 'DeprecationWarning'>, <class 'UnicodeWarning'>, <class 'ValueError'>, 
<class 'TabError'>, <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, <class 'IndentationError'>, 
<class 'AssertionError'>, <class 'UnboundLocalError'>, <class 'NotImplementedError'>, 
<class 'AttributeError'>, <class 'OverflowError'>]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not a good solution either, but it's sort of cool.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = urlopen('http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/exceptions.html').read()
>>> parsed = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> exceptions = [x.text for x in parsed.select('dl.exception > dt tt.descname')]
>>> exceptions
['BaseException', 'Exception', 'ArithmeticError', 'BufferError', 'LookupError', 
'EnvironmentError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'EOFError', 
'FloatingPointError', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'IndexError', 
'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'NotImplementedError', 
'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'StopIteration', 
'SyntaxError', 'IndentationError', 'TabError', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 
'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 
'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'ValueError', 'VMSError',
'WindowsError', 'ZeroDivisionError', 'Warning', 'UserWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 
'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'SyntaxWarning', 'RuntimeWarning', 'FutureWarning', 
'ImportWarning', 'UnicodeWarning', 'BytesWarning', 'ResourceWarning']
```

(Requires [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#))

Comment: Both of those do what I was looking for, with a little extra junk that I can live with. Thanks!

Comment: @cyd, the other answer is better: it doesn't involve scraping html.